# Segfault 11 in code using vectors and fstream? C++

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault, fstream

Im trying to write a program that takes a txt file as input, and uses ques from the words in the text file to generate a .h file (and later hopefully) a .cpp file. This code compiles fine, its just that it segfault 11's once it gets the input file. Can somebody help me out?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "12337756_Library.cpp"
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    bool a;
    string filename;
    string line;
    vector<string> Attr;

    cout << "Enter input file name:";
    getline(cin, filename);

    ifstream fin(filename.c_str());

    if (fin)
    {
        while(!fin.eof())
        {
            getline(fin, line);
            createNewFile(line);
            Attr.push_back(line); 
        }
        if(Attr[1]=="Movie.h")
        {
            bool x,y;
            //x=createNewFile(Attr[0]);
            y=createNewFile(Attr[1]);
            if(x)
            {
                ofstream fout(Attr[1].c_str());
                fout << "#ifndef HEADER_H_" << endl << "#define HEADER_H_" << endl;
                fout << "#include <iostream>" << endl << "#include <vector>" << endl;
                fout << "using namespace std;" << endl;
                fout << "enum Movie_Rating {G,PG,PG13,R,NC17,NR} ;" << endl;
                fout << endl << endl << endl;
                fout << "class Movie" << endl << "{"<< endl;
                fout << "public: " << endl;
                fout << "// ------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
                fout << "// ----- Constructors -----------------------------------" << endl;
                fout << "// ------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
                fout << endl << "Movie();" << endl << "Movie(const string& title);" << endl;
                fout << "Movie(const string& title, const string& director, Movie_Rating rating,unsigned int year,const string& path,const string& actor); " << endl;
                fout << endl;
                fout << "// ------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
                fout << "// ----- Destructor -------------------------------------" << endl;
                fout << "// ------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
                fout << endl;
                fout << "~Movie();" << endl << endl;
                fout << "// ------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
                fout << "// ----- Inspectors -------------------------------------" << endl;
                fout << "// ------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
                fout << endl;
                fout << "string getTitle() const;" << endl;
                fout << "string getDirector() const;" << endl;
                fout << "Movie_Rating getRating() const ;" << endl;
                fout << "unsigned int getYear() const ;" << endl;
                fout << "string getURL() const ;" << endl;
                fout << "string getActor(unsigned int i) const ;" << endl;
                fout << "int getActorNumber() const ;" << endl;
                fout << endl;
                fout << "// ------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
                fout << "// ----- Mutators ---------------------------------------" << endl;
                fout << "// ------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
                fout << endl;
                fout << "void setTitle(const string& title);" << endl;
                fout << "void setDirector(const string& director) ;" << endl;
                fout << "void setRating(Movie_Rating rating)  ;" << endl;
                fout << "void setYear(unsigned int year)  ;" << endl;
                fout << "void setURL(const string& path)  ;" << endl;
                fout << "void setActor(const string& actor);" << endl;
                fout << endl;
                fout << "//-----------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
                fout << "//------- Facilitators --------------------------------------" << endl;
                fout << "//-----------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
                fout << "void output(ostream & out);" << endl;
                fout <<"// ----------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
                fout <<"// ----------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
                int size = Attr.size();

                while(size!= 1)
                {
                    fout << Attr[size] << endl;
                    size--;
                }
                fout << "};" << endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `while(!fin.eof())`, the most prevalent modern C++ anti-pattern.

Comment: This looks suspicious: `#include "12337756_Library.cpp"`. Also `if(x)` when `bool x` is never initialised is distinctly dodgy.

Comment: What does your debugger say is at the top of the stack at the time of the segfault? If it's `createNewFile()`, we can't help you.

Comment: Is it a segfault or an out of range error? If there is only one file, then `Attr[1]` doesn't exist (only `Attr[0]` does).

Comment: @StackUnderflow : `std::vector<>::operator[]` does not throw out of range errors. At best, this might be an assertion.

Comment: @StackUnderflow: `at()` returns out of range, `operator[]` would segfault I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only pushed back one `std::string` so your vector only contains 1 element. To access that one element use `Attr[0]` not `Attr[1]` (there are several places you do that in the code). Remember in C++ indexes start at `0` and not `1`.

Also, in the following code `size()` returns `1`, so the while loop is never entered.

```
int size = Attr.size();

while(size!= 1)
{
    fout << Attr[size] << endl;
    size--;
}
```

Comment: If size() returned 1 you'd never even enter the loop no?

Comment: Although I aggree that the vector access is off by one.

Comment: @Jesse Good Thanks, that helped alot, there are a few other bugs, but the segfault is gone!